# How can I keep two external drives synced up?

Tags: 14.04, sync, external-hdd

I have two external drives--one is NTFS and one is ext4. Right now I am waiting for the contents of the slightly older NTFS drive to copy over to the ext4 drive. I'll use these drives at different times; NTFS for copying files from Windows, and ext4 for copying from Ubuntu, which means that the drives will have slightly different contents, but they'll both be equally as important as one as another. There will be no master copy that can just overwrite the other.

Without simply using Ubuntu to copy the drive contents across to the other drive every time I change something, how can I keep the two drives in sync?

Answer (score 2):

I use Grsync to do just that.

I copy the contents of Dropbox to my WD 1TB NAS then copy the contents of the NAS to an attached USB 1TB external drive.

The first time it runs it takes an age to complete, but thereafter it only copies changed files so runs in a flash (no pun intended).

[Grsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grsync) is a graphical frontend to rsync. You can download both from the Ubuntu Software centre.

Comment: So you think rsync is the best solution? I'll make a modified version of my backup script, then. Cheers!